# Rails migration from 5.X to 7.X Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I was migrating a ruby on rails project from rails 5.X to 7.1.3, and I have an issue with javascript from rails_admin. When I check the console, I have this kind of error:

```
 turbo.self-35ed69897…8b6888b535c.js:470 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
 
 filter-box.self-8d0c…705a1f3c23d6da.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
 
 filtering-multiselec…ee8f6f0f1831f8.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
 
 filtering-select.sel…b3f57e45795b57.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
 
 remote-form.self-daf…4986cee62b7a29.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
 
 nested-form-hooks.se…8c57e71c987be1.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
 
 i18n.self-762663bbe8…e1ce77141eccd.js:18 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
 
 widgets.self-7e1b0c9…fd01d572b034d0.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
 
 ui.self-16ae4a4a2e7c…62c6108f3fd38f.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

In the config folder I have create a file importmap.rails_admin.rb with the following content:

```
pin "rails_admin", preload: true
pin "rails_admin/src/rails_admin/base", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:rails_admin@3.1.2/src/rails_admin/base.js"
pin "@hotwired/turbo", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@hotwired/turbo@7.3.0/dist/turbo.es2017-esm.js"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@hotwired/turbo-rails@7.3.0/app/javascript/turbo/index.js"
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/esm/popper.js"
pin "@rails/actioncable/src", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/actioncable@7.1.3/src/index.js"
pin "@rails/ujs", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/ujs@6.1.7/lib/assets/compiled/rails-ujs.js"
pin "bootstrap", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js"
pin "flatpickr", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:flatpickr@4.6.13/dist/esm/index.js"
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.js"
pin "jquery-ui/", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery-ui@1.13.2/"
```

and I also have importmap.rb file with the following content:

```
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application" 
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js" 
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js" 
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js" 
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

Here is the content of the head tag in application.html.erb

```
  <head>
    <title><%= @hospital.short_name %><%= t('meta.hospital_title') %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= t('meta.description') %>">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta property="og:title" content="<%= @hospital.short_name %><%= t('meta.hospital_title') %>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<%= image_url 'merendre_ca_logo.jpg' %>"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<%= t('meta.title') %>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<%= t('meta.description') %>"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<%= image_url('touch-icon.png') %>"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/google_tag_manager' %>
    <script src="<%= javascript_url 'application' %>" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
  </head>
```

I'm a bit confused about what I'm doing wrong. I haven't work a lot with rails 7.x

I have read some documentation, but I'm still confuse about what to do.

Waiting for your advise

Comment: Did you try and upgrade straight from 5.X to 7.X, without stepping through 6 at all? [Upgrading Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-2-to-rails-6-0)

Comment: No I have done the middle step. But maybe I forgot something. I didn't notice javascript issue before being at rails 7

Comment: looks like you're doing `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` instead of `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>`

Comment: Could it be that Rails admin or its dependencies are not actually Javascript modules and thus cannot be imported as through an import map?

Comment: @Alex I have updated my question with the head tag.

Comment: you can delete this line `<script src="<%= javascript_url 'application' %>...` and a duplicate `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'...`

Comment: @Alex I remove both, but still the same result

Comment: i can only fix what you show me. rails admin has its own layout, i'm not even sure you're rendering this application.html.erb layout. from the error `turbo.self-35ed...` that is not one of your pins so you can't import/export it. also i'm not sure why you have `.self` on every file. you did remove wepacker and all the rails 5/6 javascript junk? did you switch to `config.asset_source = :importmap` in rails admin config? i never used rails admin, so just going from their docs. works fine in a new app (only had to downgrade importmap-rails to v1)